# Python regex search and replace all characters after a string

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to do something that I thought would be simple but I'm having some trouble with regex.
Specifically, I want to find `CAUGHT AN ERROR` and everything after it on the same line, and replace it with `CAUGHT AN ERROR: XXXXX`.. My understanding is that using `.*$` ([example](https://www.regular-expressions.info/completelines.html))would allow me to search until the end of the line but I am not getting an accurate replace using the for loop. How can I replace everything after the characters I search for?

```
1970-01-01 10:59:02     
1970-01-01 10:59:02    
1970-01-01 10:59:01    CAUGHT AN ERROR: rmv: cannot remove '/media/^Red^XXXXXX.jpg': No such file or directory; FROM: exec rm [file join $drive $newFile] (in USB::Write /)
1970-01-01 10:59:01    CAUGHT AN ERROR: rmv: cannot remove '/media/^Green^XXXXXX.jpg': No such file or directory; FROM: exec rm [file join $drive $newFile] (in USB::Write /media/ug)
1970-01-01 10:59:02    CAUGHT AN ERROR: rmv: cannot remove '/media/^Blue^XXXXXX.jpg': No such file or directory; FROM: exec rm [file join $drive $newFile] (in USB::Write /medi0349223^BradbuXXXXXX.jpg)
1970-01-01 10:59:02    CAUGHT AN ERROR: rmv: cannot remove '/media/^XXXXXX.jpg': No such file or directory; FROM: exec rm [file join $drive $newFile] (in USB::Write /media/usb0 XXXXXX.jpg)
1970-01-01 10:59:02    CAUGHT AN ERROR: rmv: cannot remove '/media/^Orange^XXXXXX.jpg': No such file or directory; FROM: exec rm [file join $drive $newFile] (in USB::Write )
1970-01-01 10:59:02
```

I save the above sample log in a file and then execute the following code:

```
with open(r'C:\Users\Downloads\LOG\sample.log', mode='r', encoding='utf8') as log_r:
    content = log_r.read()

dict_items = {r'CAUGHT AN ERROR: [A-Z|a-z|0-9|\.|\-|\,|\_|\{|\}|\)|\(|\/]*\+': r'CAUGHT AN ERROR: XXXXXX'}

for k, v in dict_items.items():
    content = re.sub(k, v, content)

print(content)
```

In my dictionary, I have also tried but to no avail.

```
r'CAUGHT AN ERROR: .\$'
r'CAUGHT AN ERROR: .*$'
```

Expected outcome

```
1970-01-01 10:59:02     
1970-01-01 10:59:02    
1970-01-01 10:59:01    CAUGHT AN ERROR: XXXXXX
1970-01-01 10:59:01    CAUGHT AN ERROR: XXXXXX
1970-01-01 10:59:02    CAUGHT AN ERROR: XXXXXX
1970-01-01 10:59:02    CAUGHT AN ERROR: XXXXXX
1970-01-01 10:59:02    CAUGHT AN ERROR: XXXXXX
1970-01-01 10:59:02
```

Comment: `r'CAUGHT AN ERROR: .*$'` should work.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/O1ZQID/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`r'CAUGHT AN ERROR: .*$'` is the correct regexp. But you need to use the `re.MULTILINE` flag so that `$` will match the end of lines, not the end of the whole string.

```
dict_items = {r'CAUGHT AN ERROR: .*$': r'CAUGHT AN ERROR: XXXXXX'}
for k, v in dict_items.items():
    content = re.sub(k, v, content, flags=re.MULTILINE)

print(content)
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/huvdVS)

Comment: No, the `$` should just be removed because `.` matches any char but the line break chars.

Comment: That's another possibility.

Comment: ahh the missing piece was flags = re.MULTILINE I missed that. Thanks!